# vba function to load possible values from drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in excel with data validation in a drop down list. This list is variable based on other values in the spreadsheet.

[image: Image of the value in dropdown list]

I should do a macro in VBA that inserts a random value in the cell but only among those possible.
Is there a function in VBA that allows you to read what are the possible values to be inserted in the cell?

Sorry for my English.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can give you the answer but I want you to do a google search on `.Validation.Formula1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- random value from 1 to 4:    =INT(RAND()*4)+1
- value from your list:        =index(value_range,INT(RAND()*4)+1)

in vba:

```
Option Explicit
Sub getRand()
    Dim sampleString as string

    Range("A1").Value = "mele"
    Range("A2").Value = "pere"
    Range("A3").Value = "banane"
    Range("A4").Value = "albicocche"

    sampleString = (GetRandomValueFromList(Range("A1:A4")))
    debug.print sampleString
    'to set the cell to the random value
    'add the correct cell reference
    Range("X12").value = sampleString 
End Sub

Function GetRandomValueFromList(listRange As Range) As String
    Dim rCt As Integer
    Dim sStr As String
    rCt = Int(Rnd() * 4 + 1)
    sStr = listRange(rCt)
    GetRandomValueFromList = sStr
End Function
```